# How to optimize reading and writing by playing with buffer size?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, stream, buffer

How to optimize reading and writing speed on std::ifstream and std::ofstream in standard C++/C++11 (no POSIX functions) ? (1 <- as there is several questions, these numbers identify the different points)

I don't know exactly the role of buffers so can you confirm that :

- for reading : a large part of the file is preloaded in memory (so the buffer size define the size of this large part) (2)
- for writing : data are written in memory and once the buffer is full, it is transfered from memory to the file system (3)

How to set the buffer size on std::ifstream and std::ofstream ? (4)

Considering that I work with very large binary files (several 10 GB), and that filesystems are oftenly optimal for large reading/writting, can I define a buffer size of like 100 MB ? If it will decrease performance, why ? (5)

Finally, is the default buffer "smart" in the sense that ifstream/ofstream will detect how much data you are reading/writing to the file and adapt the buffer size to provide a maximum speed ? (6)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're looking for setvbuf() or something else.  Can you clarify if an adaptive buffer would solve your problems?

Comment: IME, on Windows with VS 2010, the performance peaks around 64 KiB of buffer size for writing to `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your description of how the buffering works is correct, AFAICS.

A buffer size larger than 1 MB is unlikely to buy you anything, though. In reality, the sweet spot is likely far below that value. Note that the buffers used by `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` have nothing to do with the disk cache - that's the kernel's job, and it does it at its own discretion. The stream buffer only affect the maximum number of bytes transferred to or from the kernel with one syscall. Thus, the ideal buffer size *doesn't* depend on how much data you transfer. What is *does* depend on is

1. The overhead cost of syscalls. Higher overhead means you'll want to transfer more data in one go.
2. The overhead cost of buffer management. Probably larger for larger buffers, if anything.
3. CPU cache trashing effects. Will strongly favour smaller buffers.

Since (1) works in favour of larger buffers while (2) and (3) work in favour of smaller buffers, there will be a sweet spot somewhere. Since the CPU cache size is likely to be a couple of megabytes or so, a buffer size which approaches that limit will see a *severe* effect from (3), so the sweet spot surely lies beneath 1 MB or so. You can probably ignore (2), so it remains to estimate (1) to get a lower bound on the buffer size. Assume that a syscall costs somewhere around 1000 cycles or so, and assume that raw copying speed of CPU+memory is 4 bytes/cycle. Transferring 4k then costs about as much as doing one syscall. So with a buffer size of 20k, syscall overhead is roughly 20%, and at a buffer size of 100k it's about 4%. he ideal buffer size is thus somewhere in the range of a couple of hundred kB *independent* of the file size!.

You can probably trust your standard library implementation to get that right, unless profiling provides you with hard evidence that there *is* a buffering issue which affects performance.